# .Net how to set IsReadOnly for a property for a usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control in .NET with 2 new property

```
Prop1: Boolean
Prop2: String
```

I want to make **Prop2** **READONLY** in the property grid when the user set **Prop1** to **false**.

[image]

Comment: Define only the getter.

Comment: When prop1 is true i need getter and setter.

Comment: You've obfuscated that, but what you really might need is a class with those two members ***or*** why cant you infer `Prop1` based on whether `Prop2` has a string length?

Comment: Check the private field of Prop1 before setting Prop2, and if it's false, don't set it. Unless you mean you want to show it "dimmed", "grayed".

Comment: You can make the property gray in `PropertyGrid` using a custom type descriptor.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  Good suggestion. Sameh, see this [Customizing the PropertyGrid Control - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make the property appearance read-only (gray) at run-time based on some criteria, you need to assign a [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to your class which provides metadata about your class for property grid.

[`PropertyGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) control uses the type descriptor of the object to extract information about its properties to show. The type descriptor, returns a list of [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) objects as list of properties. Each `PropertyDescriptor` contains some methods and properties to return display name, description, and other information about the property. `IsReadOnly` property of the `PropertyDescriptor` is responsible to inform the `PropertyGrid` if the property should be read only.

**Example**

In the following example, I created a class containing two properties. `Editable` and `StringProperty`. If the `Editable` is `true` then `StringProperty` is editable, otherwise it would be read-only and will be shown as gray in `PropertyGrid`.

**MyPropertyDescriptor**

It's responsible to provide metadata for property. When implementing this class, for most properties, we will use the trivial implementation which uses original property's implementations, but for `IsReadOnly` we will decide based on the value of `Editable` property of the owner object:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptor p;
    SampleClass o;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor originalProperty, SampleClass owenr)
        : base(originalProperty) { p = originalProperty; o = owenr; }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    { return p.CanResetValue(component); }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { return p.GetValue(component); }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { p.ResetValue(component); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    { p.SetValue(component, value); }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    { return p.ShouldSerializeValue(component); }
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes { get { return p.Attributes; } }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return p.ComponentType; } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return !o.Editable; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return p.PropertyType; } }
}
```

**MyTypeDescriptor**

It's responsible to provide a list of properties for the object. For `StringProperty` which we are going to change its behavior at run-time, we will return a `MyPropertyDescriptor`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class MyTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    ICustomTypeDescriptor d;
    SampleClass o;
    public MyTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor originalDescriptor, SampleClass owner)
        : base(originalDescriptor) { d = originalDescriptor; o = owner; }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    { return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { }); }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
            .Select(p => p.Name == "StringProperty" ? new MyPropertyDescriptor(p, o) : p)
            .ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
    }
}
```

**MyTypeDescriptionProvider**

It's responsible to return a type descriptor for your object, when someone (like property grid) request type description:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(object))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type, object o)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(type, o);
        return new MyTypeDescriptor(baseDescriptor, (SampleClass)o);
    }
}
```

**SampleClass**

At last, the implementation of the class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class SampleClass
{
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
    string sp;
    public string StringProperty
    {
        get { return sp; }
        set
        {
            if (Editable)
                sp = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Further reading**

You can read about some other solutions in the following post:

- [Make a Property Read-Only in PropertyGrid](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/make-a-property-read-only-in-propertygrid/)

Comment: Solution 2 does not work at design time (in VS properties grid). Solution 3 is really dangerous (one can modify the internal state of the static readonly `Yes` and `No` fields of `ReadOnlyAttribute`) - I strongly recommend removing it from the post (and the whole "extension" `SetReadOnlyAttribute` method)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @IvanStoev  Yes, solution 2 is just written for `PropertyGrid` control, not supporting Windows Forms Designer. In fact solution 2 is like handling a control's event at run-time and doing something, it's UI code. About the extension method, the risk will happen only if someone returns `ReadOnlyAttribute.Yes/No/Default` fields as part of `Attributes` collection. I understand the risk and I'll try to handle it.

Comment: My first attempt was removing existing ReadOnly attribute from Attributes collection of the property descriptor and adding a new one. (It doesn't have any risk) but surprisingly, the property disappeared. Then I decided to update the value. If for any reason I couldn't fix the problem of removing/adding the ReadOnly attribute, probably I'll change the Post and instead of using PropertyDescriptor, will decorate the property with `ReadOnly` attribute and will change it with reflection (which doesn't have any risk.)

Comment: @IvanStoev Updated the `SetReadOnlyAttribute` extension method to remove the existing `ReadOnly` attribute from `AttributesArray` and add a new `ReadOnly` attribute. So there is no more risk about static values. Thanks for sharing the concern!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @reza-aghaei, 
Based your your detailed answer, and @Ivan comments, the follow snippet solved my problem:

```
Dim captionFld = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me)("Caption")
Dim roaCaption = captionFld.Attributes.OfType(Of ReadOnlyAttribute)().FirstOrDefault
roaCaption.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(roaCaption, True)
```

Or C#

```
var captionFld = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["Caption"];
var roaCaption = captionFld.Attributes.OfType(Of, ReadOnlyAttribute)[].FirstOrDefault;
roaCaption.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)).SetValue(roaCaption, true);
```

You can change the **.SetValue(roaCaption, true|false);**

Many thanks.

Comment: NB: this code should be added in the UserControl_Load Event.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have following attribute on the property named "Editable"

```
[RefreshProperties(System.ComponentModel.RefreshProperties.All)]
```

Add following method, and call it from the setter of "Editable" property and pass the name of the property to set read only.

```
    public void EnableDisableProperty(string PropertyName,bool IsReadOnly)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor _propDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())[PropertyName];
        ReadOnlyAttribute _readOnlyAttribute = (ReadOnlyAttribute)
                                      _propDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];

        FieldInfo _fieldToChange = _readOnlyAttribute.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly",
                                         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        _fieldToChange.SetValue(_readOnlyAttribute, IsReadOnly);
    }
```